# An event fired when UITabBarController's 'selectedViewController' changes?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

When the user changes the selected tab of a `UITabBarController`, is there an event fired to indicate that this specific action happened?

I know that `viewDidLoad` can get fired if the `UIViewController` wasn't loaded previously and in the case it was, a `viewWillAppear` gets invoked. But neither of these will tell me that the view was shown because the tab bar was selected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `tabBar:didSelectItem:` while implementing the [UITabBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarDelegate):

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```